# BouncyCastle style ThreadedSeeder

Tags: c#, random

I've written a BouncyCastle style threaded seeder and was wondering about the predictability of the data the program generates.

The reason I'm not simply using BouncyCastle is because security isn't a concern, I don't want to use a whole library just for one function, and this code is MUCH faster.

The idea is to make several threads which operate on a circular buffer (a simple array), where each thread performs a different operation on the data in the buffer. The randomness comes from thread scheduling irregularities in the OS.

How much randomness can I expect from a mechanism like this?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class ThreadedSeeder
{
    static public ulong[] buffer = new ulong[1024];
    static public bool doThread = true;

    public ThreadedSeeder()
    {
        MakeThread(Add);
        MakeThread(Multiply);
        MakeThread(Xorshift);

        Thread.Sleep(10);

        doThread = false;
    }

    static private void MakeThread(ThreadStart a)
    {
        Thread b = new Thread(a)
        {
            Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest
        };

        b.Start();
    }

    static private void Add()
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (doThread)
        {
            buffer[i & 1023] += (ulong)DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
            i++;
        }
    }

    static private void Multiply()
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (doThread)
        {
            buffer[i & 1023] *= 6364136223846793005;
            i++;
        }
    }

    static private void Xorshift()
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (doThread)
        {
            ulong y = buffer[i & 1023];

            y ^= (y << 13);
            y ^= (y >> 17);
            y ^= (y << 5);
            buffer[i & 1023] = y;

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the randomness will be pretty high, as the order and scheduling of the threads is never guaranteed (unless you are using synchronization mechanisms).

Each time you'll run the code you'll probably get different results in the array after executing.

Hope it helps!